# Group similar nested lists to one list

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list like the below example. I want to convert this list to something like `idealresult`. The first value of each list is key to group lists.
How can i convert the list?

```
mylist= [['a','abc'],['a','def'],['b','abcd'],['b','defg']]

idealresult = [['a','abc','def'],['b','abcd','defg']]
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution:

```
mylist= [['a','abc'],['a','def'],['b','abcd'],['b','defg']]

idealresult = {}
for k, v in mylist:
    idealresult.setdefault(k, []).append(v)


idealresult = [[k]+v for k, v in idealresult.items()]
print(idealresult)
```

Prints:

```
[['a', 'abc', 'def'], ['b', 'abcd', 'defg']]
```

---

EDIT (Thanks to C.Nivs suggestions):

```
mylist= [['a','abc'],['a','def'],['b','abcd'],['b','defg']]

idealresult = {}
for k, v in mylist:
    idealresult.setdefault(k, [k]).append(v)


idealresult = list(idealresult.values())
print(idealresult)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `idealresult.setdefault(k, [k]).append(v)` and just consume `idealresult.values()`